# Unable to run fsck on /dev/mmcblk0p2

Tags: fsck

Upon rebooting using `shutdown -rF now` of my Raspberry Pi 3, I am presented with `emergency mode`, however, I am unable to run `fsck -fy` on the root partition.

I am presented with the following error:

`[FAILED] Failed to start File System Check on Root Device.`

Thus, I try to run `fsck -fy` after logging into `maintenance mode`, I get the following error:

```
...snip...
/dev/mmcblk0p2 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

So, I attempt to unmount the partition using `umount -f /dev/mmcblk0p2`, but I get the following error:

```
umount: /: target is busy
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try `mount -o remount,ro /dev/mmcblk0p2` then the `fsck` again.  This should remount it read-only which might allow for a forced fsck (not sure). You cannot completely unmount the root fs on a running system.

Comment: @goldilocks I get back this following msg: `mount: / is busy`.

Comment: @goldilocks Still no reason why my system booted into emergency mode and if it does it usually boots with the rootfs as read-only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue using these steps:

1. Modify: `/etc/fstab`

   ```
   #/dev/mmcblk0p2  / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
   /dev/mmcblk0p2  /  ext4 ro 0 1
   ```

   This should mount the `rootfs` as `read-only` on the next reboot.
2. Reboot system using: `shutdown -rF now`
3. Run `fsck -fy` if the system hasn't already
4. Remount the `rootfs` as `read-write` using:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /dev/mmcblk0p2
   ```

   We need to do this in-order to complete step 4.
5. **(IMPORTANT)** Change `/etc/fstab` back to normal, thus:

   ```
   /dev/mmcblk0p2  / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
   #/dev/mmcblk0p2  /  ext4 ro 0 1
   ```

   If `/etc/fstab` doesn't get changed back to normal, then the system will always mount the `rootfs` as `read-only`.
6. Profit.

Comment: #6 is the way!!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can fix the problem if you own a copy of [Linux File System for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/), by using the following steps:

1. Insert Micro-SD card into a Micro-SD card reader and insert it into your PC.
2. Open *Linux File System for Windows* and `umount` the SD card.
3. Select the volume and click *verify*. This will run `fsck -fy` on the volume and fix any errors present.
4. Eject Micro-SD card *safely* and insert it into the Raspberry Pi.
5. Profit.